# I need to convert my timestamp of "1/1/2018 0:00" for my time series analysis. Is there a code to keep the time relevant in this function?

Tags: r, time, time-series

My goal is to highlight anomalies and trends seasonally in water quality data so I am trying to determine how I can convert and format the time stamps correctly.

I am reading in from a csv. I have tried `as.Date` but that doesn't keep the time stamp and the time of day is relevant to my analyses.

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct("1/1/2018 0:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`. Or is it day/month/year?

Comment: Note that the above code will print as `"2018-01-01"` without the time but the time is still there.

Comment: `as.Date` returns an object of class `Date` . You need a Date-Time class like stated by @RuiBarradas. See `help("DateTimeClasses")`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use as.timeDate("2019-07-02 13:33:12") from the timeDate package.